# excel formula returning range containing value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there an excel formula of chain of formulas that could return me either an array with values (or string with CSVs)  or a range address of cells corresponding to a given type/category value?

Example

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have office365 you can use `=FILTER(A:A,B:B="cat2")`

Else you need to use `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$5:$A$10,SMALL(IF($B$5:$B$10="cat2",ROW($B$5:$B$10)),ROWS($1:1))),"")` enter with `ctrl + shift + enter` and copy down.

Comment: the FILTER works like a charm. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the cell address, assuming you max have 2 times the same value:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH("cat2",B:B,0),1))& ":" & CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,MATCH("cat2",INDIRECT("B"&MATCH("cat2",B:B,0)+1 &":B100"),0),1))
```